# pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group function is not working

Tags: python-3.x, automation, whatsapp

It might sound crazy but yesterday the function pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group worked fine with me but today I do not seem to make it work. The message was sent using the group id.

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group('Groupid','Testing message',11,51)
```

But it just worked once. Now the window opens and the particular group also gets selected but the message doesn't get typed not sent.
Has this function worked for anyone?

I am using it on windows machine and python3.

Comment: [ManojBShekaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15636892) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67094852) saying "[Refer the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWi2y.png) it accepts multiple arguments. check once again, the documentation. [https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/)"

Comment: Thanks @manojbshekaris for looking into my query but this API works just once for me. Have you been able to run it multiple times?

Comment: The Answer was deleted. Answers must not only be links, which this one was. I only posted it as a comment as I though it may still be useful. I'm afraid you cannot @-ping that user, as pings don't work across posts.

Comment: oh.. I am baffled as to why it just works once and then stops working. Have you used it?

Comment: I only came across the post because I was looking at Answers marked for possible deletion. I do not know python, nor this method. I would assume you'd need to call it twice, if you want to send a message twice. Only the second time, you'll need a different time or wait 24 hours until that time arrives again.

Comment: oh. the question was about to be deleted! Thanks Scratte for help.

Comment: Not the Question. The Answer that I mentioned in my first comment :) There's a link there. Since you cannot see the deleted Answer, the link will just get you to your Question. If you have more than 10,000 reputation points, it will get you  directly to the deleted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

1. OS: macOs Big Sur 11.4
2. Browser:O Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114
3. IDE: PyCharm CE 2021.1.3
4. Pywhatkit: 5.0

I changed a line of code of the `sendwhatmsg_to_group` function to work in my environment.

I replaced the code (line 166):

```
pg.click(width / 2, height - height / 10)
```

with this:

```
pg.click(width / 2, height / 2)
```

And then it worked.

PS: The previous code was opening an application from my program bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me on Python 3.9.12 jupyter notebook

```
pwt.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly('Groupid','Testing message')
```